# web2py_uuid() returning same value over multiple invocations?

Tags: web2py

I've added a `uuid` field to the `auth_user` table, and set the `default` value of this field to `web2py_uuid()`, as in the following:

module:

```
class User_Custom(Base):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
            Field('uuid', type='string', default = web2py_uuid(), 
                        readable=False, writable=False, label=current.T('UUID')),
                ]
```

I'm using some custom functions to populate my database, and finding that each user in `auth_user` is ending up with the same `uuid` value.

`populate.py' model file:

```
def create_user():
    user_dict = dict(
          first_name = random.choice(FIRST_NAMES),
          last_name = random.choice(LAST_NAMES),
          email = ...,
          password = ..,
          )
    return db.auth_user.insert(**user_dict)

def create_profile(count = 100):
    for idx in range(count):
        user_id = create_user()
        # create a bunch of data for tables referenced by db.auth_user
```

I was under the impression that each user created in the above manner would have a unique uuid (i.e. that web2py_uuid would be invoked each time a user is created, and that it will generate a unique output each time). Is it the expected behavior that the uuid value would be uniform across all users that are generated by a single call of `create_profile()`? Is there a way to guarantee that each user will have a unique uuid value when using the `default` parameter as in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling the `web2py_uuid()` function, you are generating a single UUID and then setting that as the default value for the field. That value will persist as the default for the entire request, so any records inserted during that request will get the same UUID. If you want a separate default value generated for each insert, you must instead supply a function as the default, and the DAL will automatically call that function on each insert. So, it should be:

```
Field('uuid', default=web2py_uuid, ...)
```

Note, `default=web2py_uuid` rather than `default=web2py_uuid()`.

From the documentation:

> `default` sets the default value for the field. The default value is used when performing an insert if a value is not explicitly specified. It is also used to pre-populate forms built from the table using `SQLFORM`. Note, rather than being a fixed value, the default can instead be a function (including a lambda function) that returns a value of the appropriate type for the field. In that case, the function is called once for each record inserted, even when multiple records are inserted in a single transaction.